# I want annotation that runs after method call itself according to return type in PHP

Tags: php, reflection, annotations, aop

For example I have method that has boolean return type. I need a annotation or structure which it runs if method return true in PHP. Key point is I need separate the concerns, I don't want write this logic inside the method. Is it possible in PHP. Actually I need kind of reflection structure in  like  Java has.

Libraries that i found, don't provide this structure. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: [Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)?

Comment: Please give us some real world example (it's OK with pseudo code). It's unclear what you actually mean. Annotations in PHP isn't something you "run", it's just static meta data. You can however read Annotations using the Reflection API. You could also read about the new Attributes to see if that helps at all, but none of those will automatically trigger anything on a method call.